# Extracting information from text document into another text document

Tags: python, file, text, extract

I need to extract certain lines from a text file. Let's say I'm looking for `"abcd1234"`. The four numbers differ every time but the first four letters stay the same.

This is what I have so far:

```
infile = file ('//Users//Nhi//Documents//Gene List.rtf', 'r')
outfile = file ('//Users//Nhi//Documents//new.docx', 'w')

for line in infile:
    outfile.write("|MmarC5_\d{4}")

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

*However*, the output has literally the phrase `"|MmarC5_\d{4}"` rather than the 4 numbers that differ every time.

Comment: start reading the tutorial and the docs: [for files](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and to extract content you can use [re](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html?highlight=regex#module-re)

Comment: its much easier to get help if you have demonstrated some effort to solve the problem yourself ....

Comment: First, Python is not going to write in MS Word `.docx` format..., just use `.txt`. Second, use the `re` module (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) and Joran Beasley's answer). Keep going, update your question, and people will help you to figure out the details that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with open("somefile.txt") as f:
      print re.findall("abcd\d{4}",f.read())
```

is one way of getting anything that matches "abcd####"